# How to install rl_json on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, tcl

I'm trying to install rl_json on ubuntu 16.04.

`make install` finishes without an error but rl_json gives me

> command not found

https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json

Comment: Hi, check the first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662051/json-2-usable-format